# Google+ Login don't return gender

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus

I have been trying to do an app with Google+ Login, but I'm having problems when I want to get the gender. I can get other data like name, language, email, tag line and birthday. But with the gender is impossible.

I have tried with this permissions but still nothing.

```
plusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                    "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
            .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
                    Scopes.PROFILE).build();
```

I have tried with this 3 modes:

```
plusClient.loadPeople(this, "me");

plusClient.loadVisiblePeople(this, "");
@Override
public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status, PersonBuffer buffer,
        String arg2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.getCount(); i++) {
        showInformation(buffer.get(i));
    }
}    

plusClient.getCurrentPerson().getGender();
```

But the gender always returns 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to confirm: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get but you will only be able to see gender information if the user has made the gender field publicly available.

Comment: Yes, I had tried this link, and here I can get the gender in the web. In my profile I have the gender set as public, but still I don't get the gender.

Comment: Are you saying that it fails to show gender for you account in the web? Or are you saying it fails to show that in Android?